# R-lang / How to use R for regex (Perl) extraction

Tags: javascript, regex, r, pcre

I used a regex tester for javascript to come up with the 3 following regex cases, to extract different types of URLs from text. I would like to use these regexs (regexi?) in R for these conditions:

http URL: `(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[^\\s]+`

bitly URL: `[^https?:\/\/](bitly\.com|bit.ly)[^\s]+`

www URL: `\bwww\.[^\s]+`

Upon reading up on regex in R, it seems that using `PERL=TRUE` would allow for the conversion from javascript -> R.I tried my last regex on following on some test examples:

```
grep("\\<(\bwww\\.[^\\s]+)\\>", 
     c("wwww.google.com and other stuff", 
       "http.www.google.com"), 
     perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "grep("\<(\bwww\.[^\s]+)\>",
>   c("wwww.google.com and other stuff", "http.www.google.com") perl"

What is the syntax for using this type of regular expression in R?

Comment: You have to escape the escapes in R. E.g., `\\s`. One escape is for inputing a character string in R and the second escape for the regex.

Comment: Note that `qdapRegex::rm_url` can do this work for you

Comment: This is actually done by your OS engine. If your intent was to search for the negation of .... `" "` with a character class then you should have used `[^ ]`

Comment: Even with fixing the \\s, its not happy. @RichardScriven, it doesn't seem like qdapRegex can handle bitly URLs?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the syntax for using this type of regular expression in R?

[The R Reference Index](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf), regex:

> #### Perl-like Regular Expressions
>
> …
>   All the regular expressions described for extended regular expressions
>   are accepted except ‘\<’ and ‘\>’: in Perl all backslashed
>   metacharacters are alphanumeric and backslashed symbols always are
>   interpreted as a literal character.

So, if you want to use `\<` `\>`, you must not use `perl=TRUE`.

Besides this, you forgot to double the backslash in `\b`.